# Perforce DVCS resolve fail and P4 Fetch doesn't match P4V Fetch

Tags: perforce, p4v

I've been putting perforce's dvcs through the ringer and found a new problem that I can't seem to resolve.

1. I did a p4v fetch knowing there was a file that would conflict.
2. I chose "finish later" for the resolution.
3. I resolved the conflict with the auto merge and submitted. Verified the result are correct after submission.
4. When I attempt to fetch from p4v I get "fetch has brought down new files from the remote server etc" and indicates the same file I already resolved (status reads "in resolve").
5. I click the resolve button from the dialog and get "There are no files that need resolving".
6. If I click "finish later", there is no conflict to resolve in any auto-created changelist.
7. If I run p4 fetch from the command line I get "changelist# - no revision(s) above those at that changelist number. No changes to fetch."

Questions:

1. Why is my fetch detecting a file that still needs resolution?
2. Why does p4 fetch differ from p4v fetch?
3. How can I clean up my broken state? (e.g fetch in p4v detects no new files, tangent depot is cleaned up, etc)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to abandon any attempt to complete this operation via P4V -- the fact that it's talking about "resolve" in the context of a fetch operation (which operates by `tangent|unsubmit+resubmit` rather than `sync+resolve`) makes it impossible to tell exactly how it's fallen off the rails.

Go to the command prompt and run `p4 resubmit`.  Hopefully that will be able to complete the fetch operation.  If `resubmit` says that there's nothing to do, re-run `p4 fetch`.

Comment: Thanks again for answering. I ran resubmit -i and there is nothing to resubmit (i.e no output). I ran p4 fetch and same result as above. If I run fetch in p4v it is still in a bad state.

Comment: If `p4 fetch` from the command line says there's nothing to do, and P4V is allegedly running the same command and telling you that it's doing something else, P4V has some horrible bug.  I'd talk to support.

Comment: I've passed it along to them. Thanks again.